# Faulty Function in C++

Tags: c++, class, floating-point-conversion

Currently I have a function in an application which takes in a float as a parameter and should perform a simple multiplication and division on the value passed in. Before the value is passed into the function in the application, it is typecast to a float as the particulars of the main application deal with the numerical data in ints. Unfortunately when I pass in the value of 0.0 to the function, it does not generate an output of 1.0 (which it should from the calculation the function performs) but merely outputs a value of 0.0 and I was wondering why the calulation was failing to produce the correct output as the program compiles and the calculation is correct as far as I'm aware.

Here is the code:

```
void CarPositionClass::centre(float inputPos)
{
    if ((inputPos <= 0) && (inputPos >= -125))
    {
        membershipC = ((inputPos + 125)*(1 / 125));
    }
}
```

It should also be noted that membershipC is a float variable that is a member of the CarPositionClass.

Comment: Do other values fail? Is there a reason you're changing a global variable instead of returning the value? What is membershipC set to before calling the function?

Comment: MembershipC is initialised to 0.0, the value is global in the context of the class and requires to be set in this function before being passed into other functions of the class for processing.

Comment: I ask because it might not be changing at all. Have you tried other values? I suspect all values come back 0, but for the reasons in the answers below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `1 / 125` to, say, `1.0 / 125`.  `1 / 125` uses integer division, so the result is 0.

Or change this expression

```
((inputPos + 125)*(1 / 125))
```

to

```
(inputPos + 125) / 125
```

Since `inputPos` is floating point, so is `inputPos + 125`, and then dividing a float by an integer is a float.

P.S.  This is surely a duplicate question.  I expect the C++ gurus to lower the dup hammer any second now. :)

Answer (score 2):

The division between two integers results in an integer. At least one operand has to be a floating point type for it not to truncate the result:

```
membershipC = ((inputPos + 125)*(1.0 / 125));
//                               ^^^
```

Comment: That is even though the value of inputPos is 0.0 and therefor a float?

Comment: @Enchanter Yes, because `(1 / 125)` is truncated to `0`, so the result of the multiplication is `0`.

Comment: The division operator only considers the data types of its own operands.  Even though inputPos is a float, it's not involved in the division operation, so it doesn't influence the int-ness or float-ness of that operation.